# AWS ElasticSearch, Filebeat, Kibana: Indices managed by policy automatically set to NO even after applying policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

ES version: 7.9

Hello friends,

I am working on AWS Elasticsearch, we are currently pushing our logs to Kibana via filebeat. To avoid ES space getting filled, we have a lifecyle policy which deletes logs more than 10 days. This has worked for us since 1 month,

but now when I checked the indices, it says the index is not being managed by any policy. No one has changed that setting amongst us. What has caused this change? Any ideas?

My suspect is ilm being set to false via filebeat, but i want to be sure.

We are using following configuration via filebeat:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: [\"$filebeat_host\"]
  protocol: \"https\"
output.elasticsearch.index: \"filbeat-${TIER_NAME}\"
setup.template.name: \"filebeat-${TIER_NAME}\"
setup.template.pattern: \"filebeat-${TIER_NAME}\"
setup.ilm.enabled: false
setup.pack.security.enabled: false
setup.xpack.graph.enabled: false
setup.xpack.watcher.enabled: false
setup.xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
setup.xpack.reporting.enabled: false
```

Any ideas. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using AWS Elasticsearch, ILM settings wont help as that is related to Elastic's xpack feature.

Can you check if ISM (Index State Management) settings are correctly configured for your indices?

Since you mentioned that it worked for about a month, its possible that new the indices which were created do not have the ISM policy attached to them and hence aren't getting deleted.

Here is how to apply ISM to new indices using index templates - [AWS ElasticSearch: How to apply a policy to an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64638236/aws-elasticsearch-how-to-apply-a-policy-to-an-index/65094855#65094855)

Comment: The index is already created, I am using a single index throughout. The setting is applied via UI, but it changes back to NO automatically without any intervention.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you are not mixing "ILM" (Index Lifecycle Management) with "ISM" (Index State Management)?

Comment: No, just confirmed... :-)

Answer (score 0):

To make sure ILM is applied to your index, you can use templates:

```json
POST _template/templateName
{
  "order": 0,
  "index_patterns": [
    "your-pattern-here*"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "TODO",
      "number_of_replicas": "TODO",
      "opendistro": {
        "index_state_management": {
          "policy_id": "your policy id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Simply insert your pattern to match your indicies as well as the id of your index policy, as well as the shards and replicas you want. I find it easier to manage indicies in elasticsearch itself as you then have a central location where you manage the life cycle of your logs.